# Correlation of signals

Tags: matlab, correlation, cross-correlation

Hello i've two complex functions ( size 1x1x2501) and i need to do a correlation between these (cross-correlation).

i've tried to use this command:

```
[c,lags] = xcorr(Hmimo_tb(1,:)',Hmimo_tb1(1,:)','coeff');
```

where Hmimo_tb and Hmimo_tb1 are my two signals in which the only difference is the fact that they have been measured in different positions. The difference betweeen these two signals is max equal to 1.5e-13, so they are only affected by noise.

when i use xcorr and i go to analyze the 'c' i find that it is complex so i do:

```
abs(c)
```

in this way i have all real value, normalized around the lags 0. 
My problem is that i have to construct a matrix that has the correlation coefficients. I mean i should have something like this:

```
M=[1 corr(Hmimo_tb,Hmimo_tb1); corr(Hmimo_tb1,Hmimo_tb) 1]
```

where 1 is the corr (Hmimo_tb,Hmimo_tb) for the first on the upper side of the matrix and cor(Hmimo_tb1,Hmimo_tb1) for the other one.

Using the xcorr command i have huge problems in the analysis of the results.First of all i find only one value 1 and a lot of value very close to 0...and this is strange for me since i expected all values around the 0.8, 0.9 or 1....instead i found a lot of values like  0.001 or near this value why? how can i interpretate these values? 
from theory i know that the correlation parameters are defined as -1<=p<=1 but how is it possible that two functions with a low difference in the plot (i'm talking about 1.5e-13) are not correlated?

Hoping to find a fast help i thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you have one "1" value and the rest of the cross-correlation matrix is near zero indicates a very strong cross-correlation.  The values are normalized by the power of the two inputs, so it is not given that you will get a "1" in the output.  In fact, that indicates that the cross-correlation is nearly perfect.  The "near 0's" indicate that they are not strongly correlated at the other phases.

Comment: Ok but how can i construct a matrix with all the correlation parameters? as i've written i need something like this: [I corr(Hmimo_tb,Hmimo_tb1); corr(Hmimo_tb,Hmimo_tb1),I]. In particular i'm working on 6 measures so i have Hmimo_tb,Hmimot_tb1, Hmimo_tb2 and so on....

Comment: @Inuyasha84  What do you mean by "all the correlation parameters"?  The size of the matrices is 1x1x2501.  The first two dimensions are meaningless since they are of length 1, so I would do "xcorr(squeeze(matrix1), squeeze(matrix2));".  That will get you an array with the cross-correlation.  No need for other dimensions.

Comment: well the problem is that xcorr gives a lot of  values that i don't know how to value. for example called M1 M2 the 2 measurement i need from correlation an output matrix like this: [M11 M12; M21 M22] where M11 and M22 are to autocorrelation and so equal to 1, instead M12 and M21 are the correlation that have to tell me how much correlated (similar) are the two measurements. With xcorr how can interpretate all those values?this confuse me....

Comment: @Inuyasha84 Ah, I think I understand.  You want a single value, and xcorr gives you a bunch of values.  That's because it is calculating the cross-correlation for all the possible array offsets- kind of like a convolution.  If you just want the zero-phase answer you can get it by doing "M1 * M2' / (abs(M1) * abs(M2)')".  That should (haven't tested it" give you the zero-offset cross-correlation.  Or you could do xcorr and just take result in the middle of the output array.

Comment: yes i think you got the point but this "M1 * M2' / (abs(M1) * abs(M2)') doesn't work :( bytheway if i bring only the middle risult of the output array of the xcorr what i do with all the others?i mean the other results of xcorr are not important?

Comment: The other results aren't important if you only care about the zero-offset cross-correlation.

Comment: ok jim but all the results given by the xcorr what do they give?